# Dependency listed in pom file not found in deployed project

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55398962/hikari-wont-load-after-migration-to-aws?noredirect=1#comment97518307_55398962) that I think I may have found the root of. I have a Spring Boot app using a datasource, `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`, that is supposed to be included transitively by Spring Boot 2.0.2 with `spring-boot-starter-jpa`. However, when I run

`jar tf my.jar | grep jtds`

the driver class isn't found (we don't have a maven executable on the server to list the classpath). Everything I do to inspect the classpath reflects that the jar isn't there.

I've done this in 2 scenarios: 1) When I didn't explicitly add the jar to my pom, I got the error reported in my previous post. 2) When I **do** add it explicitly to the pom, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

Can someone tell me what's going on?? I am confounded as to why this class can't be found and loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was solved by adding the dependency with a `runtime` scope.

Answer (score 0):

Please mind, that in the Spring Boot Parent POM the [jtds dependency is only included in `test` scope](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/b828b398b5250b09a56cba63826db7ebf31b201f/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/pom.xml#L381).

If you want to use classes of this dependency also in your production code, please change the Maven `scope` to `compile`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer!  But in my effective pom, the dependency is already listed as compile.

Comment: I did as you suggested anyway, and jtds still isn't included. :-(

Comment: Ah that was close... I already thought of pointing you to `runtime` but ruling out the `test` scope was the first step to that

Answer (score 0):

> In child pom where jar is packaged, you should have
>   spring-boot-maven-plugin.   and dependency as below:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
<artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> In parent pom :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
<artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
<version>${jtds.version}</version>
</dependency>
```